# Separating data from webservice output

Tags: android, arrays, web-services, separator

How do i get individual data from this object??

```
01-31 15:37:15.783: D/Oh gosh!(24530): anyType{date=Jan 31 2013  5:11PM; name=future; id=346; description=htdutd; url=http://example.com/projects/Project/Files/380020321581257; }
```

I tried JSON, but I got an error and logcat says that JSON cannot parse in anyType. 
So how do i separate all this individual data? And when I have separated them, I would like to put them into individiual array. Is that possible?

Comment: look into this link might be helpful to you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573994/android-trying-to-parse-json-data-for-android

Comment: The object is not a valid json. I think you need to try string manipulation only.

Comment: try spliting by ';' then split again by '=' and it's definitely not JSON